# Give second column 0 value where first column shows NA for the same row

Tags: r, loops, substitution

I have a dataset with 16 columns, in pairs. One with a species name and the second with a percentage cover (so 8 columns with species names and 8 columns with integers for the percentage cover). I want the rows with NA for species name to have a 0 in the adjacent cover percentage column for the same row. How can I write a loop that does this?

> note that I can't stack the vectors they must remain in this structure for later analyses

I have tried copying numerous loops from online sources and also countless examples on SE but I can't seem to get it right. I have tried this code for starters

```
for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
  if (x$species_1[i]==NA) {x$cover_1[i] <- 0}
  else {NULL}
}
```

but it throws this

```
    Error in if (x$species_1[i] == NA) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

which I have read relates to the fact that there are NAs in the vector...so you see my conundrum...

In the end, I want all NAs for species to have a corresponding 0 in the adjacent column for percentage cover

Comment: In general, note that `x == NA` will return NA for any reasonable value of x. Because NA can be interpreted as "unknown value,"  we don't know if x takes on the value of the unknown value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
x[is.na(x$species_1), "cover_1"] <- 0
```

Comment: ah yes, spot on

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (x$species_1[i]==NA)
```

to

```
if ( is.na(x$species_1[i]) )
```

Comment: very similar and just as useful